# How do you match data stored in pivots? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, pivot-table

Let's say I have an agency and a user and I want to match the currently logged in user against agencies on age. I might write something like this:

```
$agematch = Agency::where('Age', 'like', Auth::user()->Age)->get();
```

But let's say most information like Work_Preferences is stored in pivot tables. Both users and agencies access the same Work_Preferences information, however they each have a unique pivot table set up to link to Work_Preferences. How might I perform a match query on that?

Edit: The relationships we're talking about here look something like this. I'm pretty new to this whole thing, so figuring it out manually is pretty hard.

[image: Schema]

So far I've been working with a query that looks like this, which fails predictably because I'm asking it to call the wrong thing. Work_prefs is the magic method that calls the many to many relationship with preferences.

```
$loggedinagency = Auth::user()->id;
$match_user_agency = User::with('work_prefs')->where('work_prefs', 'like', Agency::find($loggedinagency)->work_prefs)->get();
```

Comment: Got a schema? Or a better explanation of what tables you have and how they're related? This is kinda vague as-is

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple coz there's a lot of relationships but I'll see what I can put in.